# Is there an alternative to the seamless attribute that works in all browsers

Tags: css, iframe

I am making an iframe, and i want it to look like it is part of the page.
I cannot find a way that works in all major browsers.
Here is my code

```
<iframe src="page.html" width="100%" seamless>Your browser does not support iframes.</iframe>
```

But it isn't working
Can you help?

Comment: The seamless attribute is not supported, which is why it doesn't work. Your alternative would be to tweak the CSS to achieve the effect you want.

Comment: Big super fat no :P : http://caniuse.com/#search=seamless

Comment: can i do it with css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the`seamless` attribute is not supported by any of the modern browsers, you might want to emulate it with `css` to get you started:

```
iframe[seamless]{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0px none transparent;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

> Note: with IE you might need to include additional attributes to get `seamless` outlook to work:
>
> `<iframe frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" src="...">`

Comment: It's a hint you will have to tweak it for your own setup. You never provide your setup information, I have no idea what environment we are dealing with.